# Generic Pattern for querying Master-Detail-Records into nested Maps

Tags: trigger, master-detail

I'm currently looking for an elegant solution to query all related child-records of all master-objects in a specific trigger and returning them in a nested map that has the master's object id as first-level key and a map of the related records (to this specific master-record) as first-level value.

I'm implementing this to cache variables for my `MasterObjectTriggerHandler` in the [`Lightweight Apex Trigger Framework`](http://chrisaldridge.com/triggers/lightweight-apex-trigger-framework/) by *Chris Aldrige*, in case there might be a better solution than what I currently think of.

I've only gotten so far:

```
private static Map<Id, Map<Id, DetailObject__c>> getDetailsForMaster(Map<Id, MasterObject__c> ms) {

    Map<Id, DetailObject__c> ds = new Map<Id, DetailObject__c>();
    Map<Id, Map<Id, DetailObject__c>> tempReturn = new Map<Id, Map<Id, ProdEvent__c>>();
    ds.putAll([SELECT Id, id__c, master__c FROM DetailObject__c WHERE master__c IN:ms.keySet()]);

    // now some magic happens


    return tempReturn;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the child to get your map and then return the map. here is simple code sample for you.

```
Map<Id, Map<Id, DetailObject__c>> tempReturn = new Map<Id, Map<Id, ProdEvent__c>>();
    for(DetailObject__c  do :[SELECT Id, id__c, master__c FROM DetailObject__c WHERE master__c IN:ms.keySet()]){
       if(!tempReturn.containsKey(do.master__c))
                tempReturn.put(do.master__c, new Map<Id, DetailObject__c>());
    tempReturn.get(do.master__c).put(do.Id, do);
}
return tempReturn;
```